# What record-and-replay network protocol stubbing/mocking tools are there for C++ and Java?

Tags: java, c++, testing, integration-testing

I am completely new to unit testing/integration testing. I have read that unit tests should use mocks when interacting with external systems, but it seems a lot of manual work.

For external systems I mean:

- A big database that my class accesses and computes some information
- An external web service that my class accesses and retrieves a big XML
- My class implements a serial protocol that connects to an external machine and after a long dialog retrieves lots of data and computes it.

This external system is not always available as it depends on another company. Nevertheless, I want to test my application many times even if not all the external systems are available.

I am thinking of a framework (for Java and/or C++) that does the following:

- Uses some kind of spy and the real external system and the spy "records" (in a local file) all the interactions with the external system. This needs to be run only once.
- Automatically a mock is created that "replays" the previous interactions of the real system (accessing the local file). This part can be executed as many times as needed.

If my application (in the "replay" phase) calls the same methods it called the first time (the "record" phase) it should get the same results.

Does such a framework exist? If not, what alternative would you suggest?

I have implemented simulators for many external systems but it doubles my work. For example in the case of serial protocol I have to implement my "client" and also a simulator for the "server". I wonder if there's a way to avoid reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: That all sounds good and fairly standard except you are likely to need to a) write most of it to meet your needs b) refactor your code to make unit testing practical, as code written without unit testing often isn't accessible enough.  BTW If you want an Answer, you are going to need to ask a specific Question e.g. with a `?`

Comment: I added explicit questions. I think you are right about b) . Anyway, maybe, such a mocking framework could be useful even if I don't do unit testing, just to simplify the creation of a simulator for the external system (then I could add a parameter to the application to use the real external system, the recorder or the replayer). I am not sure about a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java: http://freeside.co/betamax/

For C++, here's someone's homegrown solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381622/Unit-test-and-the-man-in-the-middle

Comment: Betamax is for http and https (which is very good!) but is there anything similar for jdbc, tcp or serial? The C++ option seems to support all protocols (I haven't tested anything yet)

Comment: Searching for alternatives to Betamax I have found [rest-driver](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver), [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) and maybe [restito](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito). All of them seem to work only with HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I don't know of similar tools in Java for other protocols.

Comment: For JDBC there is JdbcProxy: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbcproxy/ According to the documentation it can be used for record and replay, but I hasn't been updated since 2006 and I haven't tried it yet.